# R coerce character vector into character and numeric

Tags: r, vector, character, numeric, coerce

I have a vector:

```
 > vek
[1] "0"    "0"    "NULL" "0"    "0"    "0"    "0"   "NULL"
```

I want to coerce vector into numeric, where is numer and string, where is string

```
> vek
[1] 0    0    "NULL"  0    0    0    0   "NULL"
```

Is it possible? How can I manage that?

Comment: I don't think it's possible. at least, not to be contained in a single vector. but why would you want that? I'm sure for your purpose there is more efficient solution

Comment: I need to put this vector into the list and then the list to json. I want to numeric values be without ""

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot have elements of different types in the same vector. But you can do it in a list. Maybe you could transform your vector in list direclty.

```
vekl <- as.list(vek)

for (i in 1: length(vekl)){
  temp <- as.numeric(vekl[[i]])
  if (! is.na(temp))
    vekl[[i]] <- temp
}
```

To avoid warnings, use this: `suppressWarnings( temp <- as.numeric(vekl[[i]]) )`. It ignores all warnings so you have to pay attention when you use this function...

Comment: It's a good idea, thank you. Maybe you know, how to avoid coersion warnings?